# Drawing a line from point to point in ActionScript3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drawing

Lets say I have two objects, and I want to use action script to draw a line connecting them, which will update automatically as they are moved/ dragged. 
Can anyone show me how to do that, and also how to control line's parameters like colour, weight etc?
Any answer would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your two movieclips `mc1`and `mc2` share the same parent: `mcParent` on an ENTER_FRAME event you would do:

```
mcParent.graphics.clear();
mcParent.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 1);
mcParent.graphics.moveTo(mc1.x, mc1.y);
mcParent.graphics.lineTo(mc2.x, mc2.y);
```

You can change the aspect of the stroke by changing the parameters of [lineStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29).

Cheers!